# Creating and saving image from byte[]

Tags: c#

I am storing an array of bytes into SQL Server. I want to create and save an image from a byte[] but several attempts seem unreliable and result in intermittent exceptions.

What is the best way to go about this?

EDIT: I got exceptions such as incorrect parameter and GDI exception. I don't have the code as this is on my machine at work.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you getting exceptions? what kind?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
image.Save("myfile.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpg);
```

If you get exceptions it is likely because your `byte[]` is in the wrong format or is corrupted/damaged.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a bitmap image, then you can create a MemoryStream from the byte array and then load the image from it. As long as the data contains valid image data that .net can decode, you shouldn't get any exceptions - so if you're doing this and getting intermittent exceptions, it's possible that the data is being corrupted or truncated during its trip to/from the database - make sure you're getting back identical data to what you attempted to store.

Otherwise, I'd suggest posting details of the exceptions so we can help you diagnose the issue.